# error: CvANN_MLP does not name a type

Tags: opencv, compilation, opencv3.0

I am compiling my program in `opencv-3.1`, but I am getting following error

```
error: `CvANN_MLP` does not name a type
```

The program is compiling properly in `opencv-2.4`.

I am not able to find `CvANN_MLP` word in any of `the opencv-3.1` header files.

Can anybody tell what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Upgrade guide](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html#gsc.tab=0) it was changed from `CvANN_MLP` to `cv::ml::ANN_MLP` in 3.0.